# Prevent bold font-weight from changing line-height

Tags: html, css

This may seem tedious, but I need to figure out a method of ensuring that all lines of a site are on the baseline grid. The problem is that the anchors are set to `font-weight: bold` and this adds what seems to be 2px of space to the top of the anchor text. Is there a simple CSS solution to this?

Comment: Post some HTML and CSS in a jsfiddle so we have something to look at... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What ended up working for me was the following CSS:

`a {line-height: 0}`

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, to avoid the observed behavior, is to set the line-height to a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Well using a CSS reset for all your sites is something you should look into: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

For example, taken from the above link:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

And you could add `font-weight: regular` to that list if necessary.

Comment: Sorry for the delete.. This is a good idea black Bird, but what did it for me was to set a `{line-height: 0}`